# Rufus scheduler.at cannot parse time on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rufus-scheduler

Error in heroku logs:
[image]

code that contains rufus scheduler:

```
def checkout_timer time, id, lpn
    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
    time_to_do = time + 1.minute
    Rails.logger.info "time_to_do: #{time_to_do}, id: #{id}"
    scheduler.at time_to_do do
      Rails.logger.info "hello, it's #{Time.now}"
      reservation = Reservation.find(id)
      if reservation&&reservation.status == 'Reserved'
        reservation.destroy
        Car.where(:lpn => lpn).update_all(:status => "Available")
        notification = Notification.new(:email => reservation.email, :message => 'You do not check out the car on time !')
        notification.save
      end
    end
  end
```

code that calls scheduler:

```
if user && @reservation1 == [] && @reservation.save
        return_timer @reservation.expect_return_time, @reservation.id, @reservation.lpn
        @reservation.update_attribute(:expect_start_time, Time.now)
        @car = Car.find_by_lpn(@reservation.lpn)
        @car.update_attribute(:status, "Checkout")
        format.html {redirect_to @car, notice: 'Rent successfully.'}
        #   format.json { render :show_reserve, status: :reserved, location: @reservation }
```

@reservation.expect_return_time gets its value from

```
 <p>
      <%= f.label :expect_start_time,'Expect checkout time' %>
      <%= f.datetime_select :expect_start_time %>
    </p>
```

It runs correctly on my local machine. And I remember that yesterday there was no problem about it on heroku. However, this weird problem happened today on heroku.

**Update:**

- Ruby version 2.3.4
- Rufus-scheduler version 3.4.2
- Et-Orbi version 1.0.6

Comment: Somebody helps please. It's urgent

Comment: What is the version of rufus-scheduler on your Heroku system? What is the version of Ruby there? Update your question with these pieces of information.

Comment: Please also indicate the version of the "et-orbi" gem on your Heroku system.

Comment: @jmettraux ruby is 2.3.4, rufus-scheduler is (3.4.2

Comment: @jmettraux et-orbi is 1.0.6

Comment: What version of Rails? What version of ActiveSupport?

Answer (score 0):

Force your Heroku to use the gem "et-orbi" at its version 1.0.5.

Please do note that starting a new Rufus-Scheduler instance for each call to `checkout_timer` is a waste of resource. And it's exposing your rufus-scheduler instance to garbage collection, if it happens before the job's appointed time, the job will not trigger.

**Update 2017-10-07**

The gem "et-orbi", used by rufus-scheduler, at version 1.0.7 contains a fix for this problem.

Comment: But if I use Rufus::Scheduler.singleton, for example, I have scheduler.in '30s' and scheduler.in '1minute', will the second one overwrite the first one?

Comment: No, it will not.

Try it for yourself: https://gist.github.com/jmettraux/8cb63397fe55896933518f2c6e52af34